# Can i getColor of a color resource for a special configuration?

Tags: java, android

For example think we have a color resource in values/colors.xml as:

```
<color name="navigation_drawer_overlay">#66000000</color>
```

And the same color resource in values-night/colors.xml as:

```
<color name="navigation_drawer_overlay">#33AAAAAA</color>
```

By default when i fetch this color in java source codes:

```
ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.navigation_drawer_overlay);
```

It will fetch base on automatic configuration detection.

But i want to fetch special configuration (in my case values-night version)

Is there a way to force fetch resource of my desire configuration?

Can i force fetch -night color resource?

Comment: I don't understand your question can you explain better? When set nigth color the color will be avaiable in night mode.

Comment: @BrunoFerreira ! problem is in some special cases, the return value of getColor is not what expected!
For example it return day value in night mode.
Probably they fixed this problem in future release of appcompat.
But for now i want to workaround this by force it to get night value.

Comment: check my answer to see if helps.

Comment: This is related to this issue: [link](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=215954)

Answer (score 2):

you can try this workaround:

1) set two **colors** inside colors.xml like this:

```
<color name="navigation_drawer_overlay_day">#66000000</color>
<color name="navigation_drawer_overlay_night">#33AAAAAA</color>
```

2) Inside **class** when you need to change color do this:

```
switch (AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode()) {

            case AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES:

                ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.navigation_drawer_overlay_night);

                break;

            case AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO:

                ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.navigation_drawer_overlay_day);

                break;
        }
```

Comment: I currently use this workaround but it is very ugly!
If we can force to get a configuration value it will very beautiful than this.

Answer (score 2):

For several years later, there is a solution:

```
    private static Context getNightContext(Context fromContext) {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration(fromContext.getResources().getConfiguration());
        configuration.uiMode = UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES; // set night mode
        return fromContext.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
    }

    // try to get the color from nightContext
```

Comment: is it newly added to android apis or it was there before? Are you test it?

Answer (score 0):

Based on answer by @user3094449

But with some modification

The correct constant for night mode is UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES, not NIGHT_MODE_YES.

```
private static Context getNightContext(Context fromContext) {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration(fromContext.getResources().getConfiguration());
    configuration.uiMode = Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES; // set night mode
    return fromContext.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
}
```